Commutation relations Klein-Gordon field
I am having a first course in QFT and we are using QFT by Mandl and Shaw. I was reading chapter 2 and I am confused as to how they get to equation 2.32. This equation depics the commutation relations. I specifically do not get this one
$$[\phi(x,t), \dot\phi(x',t)] = i\hbar c^2 \delta^3(x-x')\tag{2.32}$$
I don't see how they get the $c^2$ in this relationship.

The Lagrangian density is
$$
L= \frac 1{2c^2} \dot \phi^2 - \frac 12 (\nabla \phi)^2.
$$
From this, the momentum $\Pi(x,t)$  canonically conjugate to  $\phi(x,t)$ is
$$
\Pi= \frac 1 {c^2} \dot \phi.
$$
The standard canonical commutation relation is
$$
[\phi(x,t), \Pi(x',t)] = i \hbar \delta^3(x-x'),
$$
and so the result follows.
